# New to SQL. Want to use listagg. I'm using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a table similar to this.

| ID | Alt Number | Alt Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | R |
| 1 | 124 | J |
| 2 | 456 | R |
| 2 | 457 | J |

The output I want is as below. I have been advised to look up pivot function as well, but I fail to understand the online tutorials for these.

| ID | Alt_Info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123@R, 124@J |
| 2 | 456@R, 457@J |

Please explain it to me like I'm 5. Also, would there be another way to get the result besides listagg and pivot?

Thank you!

Comment: LISTAGG is what to use here. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466

Comment: There are other ways, but LISTAGG is superior to them.

Comment: Did you make attempt? Edit question to show that SQL. What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? You will have to concatenate fields Alt Number and Alt Name within the LISTAGG function.

Comment: Try: `select listagg(distinct Concat([Alt Number], "@", [Alt Name]), ',') within group (order by [Alt Number], [Alt Name]) as Alt_Info
from the_table`. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: @June7 concat support only 2 parameters you need https://dbfiddle.uk/TmXHBsqW

Comment: Ooops. Okay, hopefully OP now has enough info to fix. Certainly a lot simpler than it would be in Access.

Comment: Oracle supports the ANSI SQL `||` concatenation operand.